# How to add parent as a submenu <li> item using the WordPress Walker?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, wp-nav-walker

Currently, I'm trying to modify the Walker_Nav_Menu class to include the parent element twice as a **li** item in its submenu.

This is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not sure if I should modify the `start_lvl` function or the `start_el` function.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>
  <a href="linktomenu">Level 0 item</a>
  <ul class="submenu">
    <li><a href="linktoparent">Show All Level 0 item </a></li>
    <li><a href="#0">Back to parent</a></li>
    <li><a href="linktomenu">Level 1 item</a></li>
    <li><a href="linktomenu">Level 1 item</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I'm a newbie with the Walker. Can you help me with this?
I've searched previous questions, but I didn't find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

Been struggling with this myself using `start_el`, `start_lvl` and so on, I got it working by a simple string count in the output elment.

I've created a method to add the code with parent link

```
function add_link_to_parent_element(&$output, $parent_element_id){

        $parent_id = get_post_meta( $parent_element_id, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
        $parent = get_post( $parent_id, 'object' );
        $back = __('back','sage');
        $goto = __('Go to: ','sage');
        $output .= "<li class='title hide-desktop'><a href='#'><svg viewBox='0 0 10 14'><use xlink:href='#pixelarrow'></use></svg><span>$back</span></a></li>";
        $output .= "<li class='parent link'><a href='$parent->guid'>$goto $parent->post_title</a></li>";
}
```

In the `start_el` method at the beginning I used PHPs `substr_count` function to check if the links has been added to the current level.

```
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array(), $id=0)
    {
        if ($depth > 0 && substr_count($output, 'title hide-desktop') != $depth){
            $this->add_link_to_parent_element($output,$item->menu_item_parent);
        }
// rest of the start_el method
```